# Why is my applescrpt returning 2 msgbox while running the excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript

The following applescript seems to be running the macro twice as I am getting message box 2 times.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
run VB macro "Test.xlsx!Test()"
end tell
```

And the test () macro is:

```
Sub Test()
MsgBox "This is an Excel macro."
End Sub
```

I am getting the message box "This is an Excel macro." twice so I guess it is running twice. Any idea why it is running twice?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when automating excel with ruby on windows. Try running without the brackets? Not sure if AppleScript is firing twice because if them.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when an applescript is bugged, it sometimes tries to run again from the start, typically when it calls some third party application.